# HashCodeBuilder and EqualsBuilder don't work?

Tags: java, equals

I have a class. However, when I create a Set of Students with the same private member values, those students are treated as distinct. My set should filter the duplicates, but doesn't.

```
class Student {
    private StudentType m_type;
    private List<Attribute> m_attributes;
    private DegreeType m_dType

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (!(o instanceof Student)) {
            return false;
        }

        Student st = (Student) o;
        EqualsBuilder eb = new EqualsBuilder()
            .append(m_type, st.m_type)
            .append(m_attributes, st.m_attributes)
            .append(m_dType, st.m_dType);
        return eb.isEquals();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        HashCodeBuilder hcb = new HashCodeBuilder()
            .append(m_type)
            .append(m_attributes)
            .append(m_dType);
        return hcb.toHashCode();
    }
}
```

Note: StudentType and DegreeType are enums. I am using Java 8.

Comment: This is where we ask for a [mcve].  What you have presented is quite short, but it is not complete and therefore not verifiable, either.

Comment: `StudentType`, `Attribute` and `DegreeType` also has to implement hashCode and equals correctly. I'm guessing that is your problem.

Comment: If you are using Java 8 you could just use `Objects.hash(Object...)` and `Objects.equals(Object, Object)` instead

Comment: "Objects.hash(Object...) and Objects.equals(Object, Object)", where to use it?

Comment: "... when I create a Set of Students with the same private member values ..." - how about you show us the code where you do that.  Otherwise, it's impossible for us to know what you're doing wrong.

Comment: The Java naming conventions call for underscores to appear only in constant variable names, and not to use Hungarian-style prefixes.

Answer (score 0):

Without overloading the value of `equals()` for `Attribute` you're very likely comparing `List<Attribute>` using the default `.equals()` implementation in Java which is to see if the two objects occupy the same location in memory.

If you instantiated two different instances of `Student` then the `List<Attribute>` inside of the two instances will never be equal since they will be distinct lists - even if the lists contain the same exact values internally and even in the same order.

`EqualsBuilder` is not entirely magic. It's just calling `.equals()` on each inner type inside your class.

In short: it's `.equals()` all the way down. Be sure to override it for every type necessary.

Comment: The `List` type itself should implement `equals` and `hashCode` correctly, to comply with the interface. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#equals-java.lang.Object- _et seq._ So you only have to handle the `equals` and `hashCode` implementations in your own classes.